# Make a member run slash command only once discord.py

Tags: database, discord.py, modal-dialog

I've made an application command (/apply) on v2 of discord.py that pops up a modal on your screen and let you answer all the questions. However, people can access and send how many times they want; so I wanted to avoid any type of spams from members...

how may I link the database with the code so that I can print the users that have already used the command and avoid that they use it again?

Comment: I did something like this with a poll. I used a json and kept a copy of each user's Discord name in a list. Then, if a user tried to engage again, their username was compared to the list, and if they had already voted, they got a different message. At that point, the user can use the command as many times as they want, but will only get the desired result the first time.

Comment: I suggest to use a database. If your bot gets on more server or the servers gets more members it's better to use a database. Also, using a database is always a good practice for those things.